# How to type-cast char* to int* in openCL

Tags: c, visual-studio, pointers, opencl

Can any one tell me how to typecast a `char*` pointer to `int*` in OpenCL kernel function??
I tried `((int*) char_pointer)` but it is not working.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Make sure that you disable strict aliasing in the compiler, such operation isn't legal due to the strict aliasing rule, but in most compiler, you can turn it off.

Comment: /tmp/OCLqZ3crS.cl(710): error: invalid type conversion
      a[0]=*((int*)allocatedBuf);   allocatedBuf has type global char*

Comment: Build Options are : -fno-strict-aliasing
Error: Program::build() failed. Error code : CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS

Comment: i know this has been answered & accepted but out of interest, you *do mean that you want to store 4bytes at address `allocatedBuf` as an `int` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to qualify the pointer with the correct address space, I think.

If you don't specify the address space, `__private` is assumed, but your source pointer seems to be a `__global` pointer (from your comment), so the address spaces are incompatible.

So try to use `(__global int*)` instead of just `(int*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff the pointers in a union, initialize with a char*, use it with the int*:

```
 union {
     char *cp;
     int  *ip;
 } ptr;

 ptr.cp = allocatedBuf;
 a[0] = *(ptr.ip);
```

Ugly, but does the trick without casts, at least in C. It's undefined behaviour, but hey, you're not using this in a heart monitor or with nuclear warheads at the other end, right?

Comment: What happens if the code will be open sourced and some company will use it in a nuclear plant one day?

Comment: I think this isn't even UB, since OpenCL C explicitly allows reading a different union member than the last written one (at least if the sizes match, which is the case here). This may be even the case with C99, on which OpenCL C is based, but I'm not sure about that. But it won't solve his problem, anyway, since it lay in the mismatching address spaces.

Comment: They can't blame me, because I told them so. Seriously, the same will happen than with the cast in the accepted answer. Using a misaligned pointer is always asking for trouble.

Comment: @Jens Ah yes, haven't thought about alignment. Ok, then it *can* indeed be UB. Let's just hope he's taking care of alignment correctly (or we get rid of nuclear plants until someone discovers his code be it only for that reason).