# How to convert char array to double in opencl?

Tags: arrays, char, double, opencl

I want to create a function that converts a char array to double. I will call this function inside my kernel and pass a pointer to the char array. But there seems to be a problem with it. I can't use bit operations with double

```
double toDouble(uchar* ptr)
{
double value;
value = *ptr << 56;
value |= *(ptr+1) << 48;
value |= *(ptr+2) << 40;
value |= *(ptr+3) << 32;
value |= *(ptr+4) << 24;
value |= *(ptr+5) << 16;
value |= *(ptr+6) << 8;
value |= *(ptr+7);
return value;
}
```

This gives 1 error "invalid operands to binary expression('double' and 'double')"

This also gives me a warning "shift count >= width of type".

But when I do the same thing with an int or long (create a similar function toInt and use the bit operations), I do not get any error. Is this a correct way of converting uchar array to double ?

I have also tried this

```
double data;
uchar* dataptr=&data;
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    dataptr[i]=ptr[i]; //where ptr is the pointer to the uchar array
```

But this gives me an error "illegal implicit conversion between two pointers with different address space"

Comment: For your second error, you need to typecast the pointer.. here's something related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483445/how-to-type-cast-char-to-int-in-opencl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of OpenCL follows the C99 standards with the exception of hardware vendor support of floating point values and some oddities.

With that in mind, let us see the C99 standard on bitwise operators:
"Bitwise operators only work on limited types: int and char (and variations of int). You can, with some casting, make it work on other types. These operators, in conjunction with bitshift operators allow you to access and modify bits." http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitwise.html

So, what does this mean? You need to do the operations on a type that is capable of the bitwise operators. You also need to make sure it is of the same bit size. So, looking at double, being a 64-bit value. We can use bitwise operators on long, a variant of type int and it is 64-bits. After doing this, you would need to do a cast on long to a double, then you can return your value. So your code would look something like this:

```
    long value;
value = *(ptr) << 56;
value |= *(ptr+1) << 48;
value |= *(ptr+2) << 40;
value |= *(ptr+3) << 32;
value |= *(ptr+4) << 24;
value |= *(ptr+5) << 16;
value |= *(ptr+6) << 8;
value |= *(ptr+7);

double value2 = (double)value;
```

This worked fine. But you need to check how your version of OpenCL can cast values. Here is a reference to get you started. OpenCL 1.2 is common in newer AMD cards, but if you have a NVIDIA card, I would look at 1.1 specifications: https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf