# Cast local pointer

Tags: opencl

I have a local uchar pointer, and I would like to cast it to a local ulong pointer.

i.e.

```
 local uchar* foo;
 local ulong* bar = (local ulong*)foo;
```

When I do this, the memory bar points to does not equal the memory that foo points to.  Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this pages:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/the-generic-address-space-in-opencl-20

http://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/opencl-c/

[How to type-cast char* to int* in openCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483445/how-to-type-cast-char-to-int-in-opencl)

```
void foo(global unsigned int *bar)  // ‘global’ address space on bar, works in both OCL 1.2 and OCL 2.0 with no additional flags to compile

    {

        local unsigned int *temp = NULL;//’local’ address space on temp, works in both OCL 1.2 and OCL 2.0 with no additional flags to compile

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. The second link was quite relevant. It seems that because of compiler settings, it is not legal to cast, at least for local memory.  So, I ended up refactoring to avoid the cast.

Comment: It is illegal to cast *between* address spaces. Different types in the same address space should work.